# confusion with the term openssl_private_encrypt

Tags: php, encryption, sign

In encryption, we use the public key of the receiver, why the "private" term in the function? Seems contradictory or confused to me.

When I use private key, I am signing something. Looks like this function would give the same result as `openssl_sign()`, I tried both and gave me different output.

Because the function `openssl_private_encrypt` has "private" and "encrypt", I don't know if it is for encrypting or for signing.  What is this function for?

Comment: arguing about php function names will get you [nowhere](http://xkcd.com/650/)

Comment: sorry, function referred in first paragraph is openssl_private_encrypt()

Comment: In SSL, the *sender's* **private** key is used to *encrypt*.  The opposite function is `openssl_public_decrypt`, since the *receiver's* **public** key is used to *decrypt*.

Comment: if you can help me what is this function openssl_private_encrypt for, I could get somewhere.

Comment: @user1873420: The docs explain what it does pretty well: http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-private-encrypt.php

Comment: Ok, so I have to use openssl_public_encrypt, I got it, thanks a lot Rocket

Comment: Tried it, and got: "openssl_public_encrypt(): key parameter is not a valid public key", refering to the third parameter, which is the private key file.

Comment: segment fo code is:$llave_priv = file_get_contents("i.pem"); $plaintext = "f2e140eb-2b09-44ab-8504-87b25d81914c";
openssl_public_encrypt($plaintext, $encrypted, $llave_priv); //i.pem is private key file

Comment: @user1873420: You use `openssl_private_encrypt` to encrypt (using a private key), then `openssl_public_decrypt` to decrypt (using a public key).

Comment: @Dagon I think this is a fine question on the use of an API method, no need to vote down or to close (unless there is a dupe). If the use of a method is unclear, there is every reason to argue about it.

Comment: @RocketHazmat You are both incorrect in saying that you can use a private key for encryption as well as indicating that SSL uses a private key for encryption.

Comment: It's a pre-historic OpenSSL function.

Answer (score 2):

Generally the OpenSSL encrypt with private key method is used to provide for a very specific SSL method of signature generation:

> Concatenating outputs from multiple hash functions provides collision
>   resistance as good as the strongest of the algorithms included in the
>   concatenated result. For example, older versions of TLS/SSL use
>   concatenated MD5 and SHA-1 sums; that ensures that a method to find
>   collisions in one of the functions doesn't allow forging traffic
>   protected with both functions.

Source: see the Wikipedia page for the [cryptographic hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function#Concatenation_of_cryptographic_hash_functions) and look up concatenation of cryptographic hash functions.

As most libraries don't provide a signature format like that (and since the SSL version of the signature does not use an embedded ASN.1 structure around the hashes) this is implemented most of the time using an encrypt function instead. The difference that you are experiencing is probably the missing ASN.1 structure (see the PKCS#1 v2.1 standard to see what ASN.1 structure I'm talking about).

You can place a pretty good bet on that it uses the PKCS#1 padding for *signatures* instead of the padding used for encryption. And, as indicated, it won't contain the ASN.1 structure or the hash, instead it will just use the given put the given data in place of the ASN.1 structure.

It is not recommended to use this function outside support for existing (deprecated) protocols. If you use it for encryption purposes you **will** make yourself vulnerable to all kinds of attacks, so please don't make that mistake.

Comment: I hope this answer also sheds some light on your previous questions :)